# JavaFX - FXML access Spring Beans with EL

Tags: binding, javafx-2, javafx, javabeans, fxml

i'm working with JavaFX and the gui definition is written in .fxml-Files.

Is it possible to access Beans in the ApplicationContext from the .fxml file? Like EJB-JSF Binding?

thank you in advance

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227809/displaying-changing-values-in-javafx-label

Comment: Thanks for the reply - know the binding mechanismus of javafx but is there a more comfortable way like:
Bean in Application Context
On FXML: text=$(<beanName>.<fieldToAccess>)
That would be awesome - couldn't find anything

Comment: this the way which define by javafx...other wisw you can use events like this stackoverflow.com/questions/19773792/change-label-javafx-on-keyboard-input

Comment: Thank you for your Reply ! Don't like that way so much, but it seems that i have to do it :). Thank you !