# Text Area addtext from ArrayList Without the Comma (,) in JavaFX

Tags: listview, arraylist, printing, javafx, textarea

I have an Arraylist `AList` which has over 100000 items. I need to show each and every data item in the UI. But `TeaxtArea.addtext(AList);` shows data in this manner

> [A,B,C,D..........]

likewise. What I need to do is to print this in ta a page. So I have to pass the node tho the `PrinterJob`.

Is there Anyway that I can remove the commas and replace it with newline all at once. I can not use `appendText` hence appending 100000 items make the UI non respond.

PS:  I have already collected the data From a Thread and Have it on an ArrayList. I do not have a problem in updating it on a ListView, But there is a issue when did it on a TextArea. I wont to change the format of printing without using Append

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx - Updating GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554814/javafx-updating-gui)

Answer (score 0):

You could preprocess the list and create a new String using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for( int i=0; i < 100000; i++) {
    list.add("This is line nr " + i);
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for( String text: list) {

    if( sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append("\n");
    }

    sb.append(text);
}

textArea.appendText(sb.toString());
```

Setting the initial capacity might also help in case of such a large collection.

If you use Java 8, you may also want to take a look at [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

Comment: Yes this method Kind of works But It makes my UI Unresponsive due to the large set of Data. This does not happens with the `ListView`

Comment: A TextArea is different to a ListView. The ListView is optimized for rendering only the parts you see whereas the TextArea renders all at once.

Comment: Any Suggestions for me how to improve this? My UI gets stuck when render all at once. I tried Throttling before But takes a massive amount of time.

Comment: If the strings are already in a list, using `list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))` is simpler than using a `StringJoiner`.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider aList as the ArrayList of String,

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
        aList.add("A");
        aList.add("B");
        aList.add("C");
```

Then use this code before you go to the PrinterJob,

```
StringBuffer listText = new StringBuffer();
for(String s : aList){
    listText.append(s+"\n");
}
System.out.println(listText);
```

Try this...