# Timer in javafx application

Tags: javafx, timer, controller, fxml

I'm trying to display a timer which counts and displays seconds in a label after clicking the start button but I'm not getting desired output.Here's my code of the controller and FXML file...

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private static final Integer STARTTIME = 0;
    private Timeline timeline;
    private Label timerLabel = new Label();
    private IntegerProperty timeSeconds = new SimpleIntegerProperty(STARTTIME);
    Button button = new Button();


    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (timeline != null) {
            timeline.stop();
        }
        timeSeconds.set(STARTTIME);
        timeline = new Timeline();

        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(STARTTIME+1),
                                    new KeyValue(timeSeconds, 0)));
        timeline.playFromStart();
        timerLabel.textProperty().bind(timeSeconds.asString());

    }



     public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
         // TODO

     }    

}
```

and this is my FXML code..

```xml
<Button fx:id="button" layoutX="120.0" layoutY="40.0" 
        mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start Timmer" onAction="#handle" />
<Label layoutX="132.0" layoutY="92.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="65.0" 
       textFill="#f20b0b">
    <font>
        <Font size="24.0" />
    </font>
</Label>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying changing values in JavaFx Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227809/displaying-changing-values-in-javafx-label)

Comment: Your code is not easy to follow. If any `Node` is defined in `FXML`(has a `fx:id`), you need to start it with `@FXML` and not put `= new ....` on the end of it.

Comment: You `Label` don't seem to have an `fx:id` in your `FXML`.

Comment: You basically need to look over some beginner tutorials. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `Timeline` correctly.

The duration of the `KeyFrame` is the offset from the start of the animation when the update is executed. Multiple clicks on your button all add `KeyFrame`s that run 1 second after the start of the animation.

Furthermore using `KeyValue` interpolates the value from the current value to the value passed to `KeyValue`. This makes little sense, if the new value is the same as the old value.

You should instead use a `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` to update the property.

Furthermore the `button` field should be injected by `FXMLLoader`. This requires the field to be `public` or annotated with `@FXML`.

```xml
<Button fx:id="button" layoutX="120.0" layoutY="40.0" 
        mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start Timmer" onAction="#handle" />
<Label fx:id="timerLabel" layoutX="132.0" layoutY="92.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="65.0" 
       textFill="#f20b0b">
    <font>
        <Font size="24.0" />
    </font>
</Label>
```

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private static final int STARTTIME = 0;
    private Timeline timeline;
    private final IntegerProperty timeSeconds = new SimpleIntegerProperty(STARTTIME);

    @FXML
    private Label timerLabel;
    @FXML
    private Button button;

    private void updateTime() {
        // increment seconds
        int seconds = timeSeconds.get();
        timeSeconds.set(seconds+1);
    }

    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        button.setDisable(true); // prevent starting multiple times
        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), evt -> updateTime())); 
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE); // repeat over and over again
        timeSeconds.set(STARTTIME);
        timeline.play();
    }

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        timerLabel.textProperty().bind(timeSeconds.asString());
    }    

}
```